# Extract the content(text) of a url using TIKA

Tags: java, apache-tika

How can I extract the text from a url? In my code it is extracting the source code of that url...

```
DefaultHttpClient client = null;
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test", "test"));
client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);                
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://somehost.com");        
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();

Tika t = new Tika();
Metadata md = new Metadata();
Reader r = t.parse(content, md);
System.out.println(md);
System.out.println("Yes1: " +md.get("keywords"));
System.out.println("Yes2: " +md.get("title"));
System.out.println("Yes3: " +md.get("authors"));

//This gives the source code of that url not the actual content...
String ss= t.parseToString(content);
System.out.println("Yes4: " +ss);
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've read .. you can do it with tika using this code

```
 byte[] raw = content.getContent();
 ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
 Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
 Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
 parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(raw), handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
 LOG.info("content: " + handler.toString());
```

even though I test it but I found that handler.toString() is empty !

Answer (score 1):

The [BoilerpipeContentHandler](http://tika.apache.org/0.9/api/org/apache/tika/parser/html/BoilerpipeContentHandler.html) allows you to extract the body content without markup.  The included command line utility shows how to use it in your program and to test the various formats.

Comment: dude that class is part of tika!

Comment: Any example will be appreciated based on my code.. And If you can give me the links of some example that will be great...

Comment: As I said in my reply, Tika comes with the sources of the command line utility, and that utility can do what you want, so I suggest you go there to see how it works and maybe even borrow a couple of lines of code.